# Facebook graph requests ids differences

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a REST Api which has campaign_id, user_id and pictures_id I'm thinking how can process requests to my.api.com/some_id and to know if it's a campaign_id, user_id or picture_id like Facebook knows that?

Comment: I'm not too sure Facebook will be willing to share with us the inner workings of their servers. I don't see how knowing this information would be helpful to us end users... What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm building a REST Api which has campaign_id, user_id and pictures_id
I'm thinking how can process requests to my.api.com/some_id and to know if its a campaign_id, user_id or picture_id like Facebook knows that

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to explain that in your post rather than asking how Facebook does it.

Comment: You could add an extra character to the ID (or use the first/last one) to indicate the type of resource... Alternatively, you can just use explicit endpoints:  `my.api.com/images/some_id` or `my.api.com/users/some_id`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to know without a call to Facebook. One trick would be to use the graph API schema endpoint.

`graph.facebook.com/v2.4/schema/*{your_object_id}` will return all properties of the object, along with a `base_type` node, that'll let you know what kind of object you're dealing with.

So `graph.facebook.com/v2.4/schema/*4` is a `user` (Zuck!)!